# Program type already present: com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator

Tags: android

I added a library that generated this error when trying to build the app:

```
Program type already present: com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator
```

the library is:

```
implementation 'net.steamcrafted:load-toast:1.0.12'
```

and my gradle is:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.specyci:residemenu:1.6+'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.5.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.10.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.13.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:4.0.0'
    implementation "com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1"
    implementation 'com.lusfold.spinnerloading:library:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.AndroidDeveloperLB:AutoFitTextView:4'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.3.0'
    implementation 'net.steamcrafted:load-toast:1.0.12'
    implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.13.0') {
    transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:rx:3.3.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

}

And when I remove this library, my app will build and run successfully
What is the problem with this library ? and What is causing this conflict ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem usually come from a naming conflict, in your case the [com.nineoldandroids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids) library, which might be in use by other libraries.

simply add this exclusion to your library:

```
implementation 'net.steamcrafted:load-toast:1.0.12'{
exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids'
}
```